# SQL select statement filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Ok, so I'm trying to select an amount of rows from a column that holds the value 3, but only if there are no rows containing 10 or 4, if there are rows containing 10 or 4 I only want to show those.

What would be a good syntax to do that? So far I've been attempting a CASE WHEN statement, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(My database is in an MS SQL 2008 server)

Comment: Thus, in a nutshell, "If there are rows with 10 or 4, then select rows with 10 or 4, else select rows with 3" ?

Comment: do you want the SUM() of the "amount" column?, can you also give us the few columns that would be the basis?  ie: an ID column to group by (such as account, or transaction, etc) that you need to know if 10 or 4 is applicable or not.

Comment: additionally, if there are 10 or 4 records... would you want those amounts EXCLUDED from such summarization in the query?

Comment: @cc0: Your question title and your question text diverge. Please explain closer or make up your mind. ;)

Comment: @BalusC: Exactly

@DRapp: No summing, just a list of all those columns.

I basically need to list all rows from the column that has 3, these will be related to a name column which I
m interested in.

However if there are rows in the column with the values either 10 or 4, I only want those printed.

Comment: from assumed samples.  Can you do a dump of some of these sample row/columns in question for your compare.  It looks like your comparing multiple columns in a single row vs multiple rows, even by your initial sentence...

Comment: Actually I got what I needed, thanks guys for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of your table and its indexes, it may be more efficient to calculate which values you want before the query

```
declare @UseThree as bit = 1;
if exists (select 1 from testtable where rowval in (10,4))
set @UseThree = 0;

select COUNT(*) 
from testtable
where (@UseThree = 1 AND rowval=3)
    OR
    (@UseThree = 0 AND rowval in (10,4))
```

Comment: This is a good idea. Thank you, I will implement this right now.

Comment: cudos to MrGumbe for being able to determine what the OP wanted!

Answer (score 4):

Use a `union all`:

```
select
    // columns
from YourTable
where YourColumn = 3 and not exists (
    select 1 from YourTable where YourColumn = 10 or YourColumn = 4)

union all

select
    // columns
from YourTable
where YourColumn = 10 or YourColumn = 4
```

Comment: We're missing something...  Even in your example, you're comparing the same column for a 10 or 4 when not a 3.  So it would imply multiple records in the table... Unless there's some other basis, a table could be FILLED with 3s, 4s and 10s and would always be self-excluding as a result.   I think BalusC needs to clarify more detail about his actual structure and sample record basis.

Comment: @DRapp: I'm actually comparing for a `3` when there are no `10` s and no `4` s. If his condition is based upon a subset of the data, it would be trivially simple to add that condition to the `where` clauses of the queries.

Answer (score 2):

**FYI**: Orginal question title was "**SQL CASE WHEN NULL - question**"

---

```
CASE WHEN YourColumn IS NULL THEN x ELSE y END
```

Since there is nothing that compares to NULL and returns true (not even NULL itself), you cant't do

```
CASE YourColumn WHEN NULL THEN x ELSE y END
```

only

```
CASE ISNULL(YourColumn, '') WHEN '' THEN x ELSE y END
```

but then you lose the ability to differentiate between NULL and the (in this example) empty string.

Comment: @KM: Yes, that's always the core problem. ;-) Thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to do this in two queries:

```
SELECT ... FROM YourTable WHERE SomeColumn IN (10,4)
```

If and only if the above query yields no results, then run the second query:

```
SELECT ... FROM YourTable WHERE SomeColumn = 3
```

Running two queries may seem "inelegant" but it has advantages:

- It's easy to code
- It's easy to debug
- It often has better performance than a very complex solution
- It's easy to understand for a programmer who has to maintain the code after you.

Running two queries may seem like it has extra overhead, but also consider that you won't run the second query every time -- only if the first query has an empty result.  If you use an expensive single-query solution, remember that it will incur that expense *every time*.

Comment: You make some good points, but I feel this would be a bit of a clumsy solution in my case as the database is interfaced with a website